# Problema Menu que no coje los enlaces

Tags: mysql, pdo, php7

Pues eso estoy haciendo un menu incorporando los datos del menu y submenu desde una base de datos y resulta que los enlaces van a medias:
Este es el menu:

```
Inicio 
Componentes
      Placas Base
      Memorias Ram
      Discos Duros 
Perifericos 
Contacto
```

Pues desde el inicio puedo ir bien a placa base, memorias ram y discos duros y entre ellas tambien pero el problema viene que cuando quiero ir del submenu al menu como inicio no coje el el enlace y es lo unico que me falta de acabar para acabar el menu.
conexion.php

```
<?php
try{
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tienda;charset=UTF8","root","");
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

menu.php

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY id";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $sub_sql ="SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE cat_id=:id";
        $sub_stmt = $pdo->prepare($sub_sql);
        $sub_stmt->bindParam(":id",$row->id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $sub_stmt->execute();
        echo "<li><a href=>".$row->nombre."</a>";
            if($sub_stmt->rowCount()){
                echo "<ul>";
                    while ($sub_row = $sub_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
                        echo "<li><a href=".$sub_row->href.">".$sub_row->subnombre."</a></li>";
                    }
                    echo "</ul>";   
                }
        echo "</li>";       
    }
    ?>
```

Php 7 con PDO

Comment: No tienes nada asignado en el `href` del menu.

Comment: ya pero tanto los menus como los submenus y enlaces los deberia de cojer de la base de datos, pero por mas que modifique esa linea de href vacia no me los coje por mas que la cambie, en cambio la de submenus si funciona a la perfeccion